# How to read a file from another children dir of the parent dir of the current dir in Java?

Tags: java, io

How to read a file from another children dir of the parent dir of the current dir in Java? The scenario arise when one have all the source code the `/pkg/src` and files need to be read in `/pkg/files`. What is the most elegant/logical way to do it? And what is the most primitive way to do it (without messing with absolute path of anything)?

Comment: You can read any file you with the same way in java. `new FileInputStream(new File('any/name/you/like'))`

Comment: Where the source code is is completely irrelevant. It won't be there at runtime. You have to decide where the file will be at runtime. You can control it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I don't understand, I do not have any software development experience. Can you elaborate please? Where will I be at runtime?

Comment: Your questions don't make sense, or at best are too broad to answer here. Ask a colleague.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work assuming all of the files are not inside the Jar:

```
../files
```

Where `..` means the parent directory. If this is all inside of a Jar, you can refer to it with:

```
pkg/files
```